# Gradient Background on UITable View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to set Gradient Background on UITable View Controller?

If I implent the above code, the gradient colours works well but I can't able to view the UIImage view, UIButton in the screen.. I can only able to see the gradient colour.. please help...

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setGradientBackground()

    }

    //Mark:- Gradiant background colour

    func setGradientBackground() {


        let topColor = UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 163/255, blue: 203/255, alpha: 1)
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 131/255, green: 197/255, blue: 86/255, alpha: 1)

        let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 0.5]
        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your viewcontrollers full code?

Comment: @AngryWarden..Thanks for come forward to help me... : )

Comment: I need you to copy the full code and paste it here

Comment: It is full code.. It starts from import UIKit

Comment: Where is the table view functions?

Comment: @AngryWarden...Oh..Sorry...I am new for swift language... Can you please tell me what delegate or data source function I need to add

Comment: Can you contact me on Skype, (rawandahmad10@outlook.com)

Comment: ok... see you there in Skype

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `backgroundView` of the `tableView`. Initialize an Uiview your gradient view, set it's bound equal to tableView, do all necessary stuff to setup your gradient, set this UIview as your tableView's background view.